# [Python][Pydev] Unknown encoding: MS950_HKSCS

Tags: python, eclipse, python-3.x, encoding, pydev

I have a fresh install of Python 3.4 and Pydev with Eclipse Luna.

When I try to run a simple code (like `print("Hello")`) for the first time, I see this error:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
LookupError: unknown encoding: MS950_HKSCS
```

I assume that the system cannot find ms950_hkscs.py but I cannot find a similar file on the internet.

Does anyone know what the problem is and how this can be fixed? Thanks.

Comment: `MS950_HKSCS` is not a [supported encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).

Comment: What should I do about it? Should I remove MS950_HKSCS from some kind of list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Right click on source file. 
-> Properties.

and change file encoding.